# Is there a way to remove algolia/scout from laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, algolia

im am new to laravel and I recently installed Alogila on my Laravel application as I was working on a searching functionality using Laravel scout. The command I typed was **composer require algolia/scout-extended**

I am getting an error saying **Impossible to connect, please check your Algolia Application Id.** 
Since I have decided to not have a searching functionality in my application, I would like to remove algolia from my app. I am unsure of how to do this, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: just run this command `composer remove algolia/scout-extended`

Comment: You are welcome :), if the answer helped you accept it

Answer (score 1):

You have two way to do that

**first way**
run the command

```
composer remove algolia/scout-extended
```

**Second way**
remove it from your `composer.json` file

then run the command

```
composer update
```